# how to set the content size of uiscrollview after zoomin in UIPinchGesture in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have to implement `UIPinchGesture` in iphone for that my code as follows:

```
    - (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {
      if ( [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
            [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged ) 
     {
     NSLog(@"=======Scale Applied===========");
     if ( [recognizer scale]<1.0f ) 
     {
         [recognizer setScale:1.0f];
     }
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale([recognizer scale],     [recognizer scale]);
    self.view.transform = transform;
```

}

This code is working fine for zooming in and zooming out but when i zoom in i am not able to 
scroll the view so that i can read the text on the view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `UIScrollView` instead your `UIView`. Once you have done this, you have to resize the content size of your scroll view.

```
[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)]
```

if the content is bigger than the screen the scrollview is automatically scrollable.

Hope it helps.